# python get stacked and wont continue working, am i using to much data

Tags: python-2.7

i am making a conversion of a list that contains more than 10,000 values, but Python always stops at the data n#2530, i think that i am asking python to make numerous iterations, that eventually it can no longer process more data. i would appreciate your help and thank you in advance.

code:

```
def conver(x,y,z,h,latitudes,longitudes):
size_data= len(x)

for i in range(0,size_data):
    degrees_long,degrees_latitude,height=ECEF_WSG84(x[i],y[i],z[i])
    latitudes.append(degrees_latitude)
    longitudes.append(degrees_long)
```

info: i am using python 2.7

computer:

-processor: AMDFX(tm)-9590 Eight-core Processor 4.70GHz

-memory RAM: 16GB

-Operative system: 64bits

The function ECEF_WSG84(x[i],y[i],z[i]) that i use, makes interations to find the aproximate value of the latitude, but it can find the longitude without using iterations, here is the code:

```
def ECEF_WSG84(x,y,z):
a=6378137
#1/f= 298.257224
i=298.257223563
f=1/i
degrees_long=inverse_tangent_longitude(x,y)
degrees_latitude,height= inverse_tangent_latitude(x,y,z,f,a)
return(degrees_long,degrees_latitude,height)

def inverse_tangent_latitude(x,y,z,f,a):
e= 8.1819190842622/100
r= math.sqrt((x**2)+(y**2)+(z**2))
p =math.sqrt((x**2)+(y**2))
initial_latitude= math.atan2(p,z)

new_latitude= initial_latitude

task= False
while (task==False):
    c_latitude =1/(math.sqrt(((math.cos(new_latitude))**2)+(((1-f)**2)*((math.sin(new_latitude))**2))))
    Rn_latitude= a*c_latitude


    h_latitude= (p/(math.cos(new_latitude)))-Rn_latitude
    next_latitude= math.atan((z/p)*((1-((e**2)*(Rn_latitude/(Rn_latitude+h_latitude))))**-1))

    rest= next_latitude-new_latitude

    if (rest==0):
        task=True
        degrees_next_latitude= math.degrees(next_latitude)
        return(degrees_next_latitude,h_latitude)

    else:
        new_latitude= next_latitude
        task= False


def inverse_tangent_longitude(x,y):
#we must determine the location of the Longitude.
if (x<0)&(y>0):
    a=180+math.atan(y/x)

elif(x<0)&(y<0):
    a=180-math.atan(y/x)

else:
    a=math.atan(y/x)
degrees_a=math.degrees(a)
return(degrees_a)
```

Comment: When python stops, what values are `x`,`y`,`z`? I can't reproduce the problem, but I only assign `x`,`y`,`z` to 5,6,7 and it produces the expected result.

Comment: oh thank you for answering. i am using a ellipsoidal aproximation for representing positions on the earth. now because i am assuming earth is an ellipsoid, not a circle, i have to iterate in order to obtain my altitude and latitude. So a normal value, for me of x,y,z, are the exact coordinates of a point, on a ECEF (earth centered-earth fixed) reference system, which i am using. the values of x,y,z, can vary from 0-6340000m. now the thing is that i have 3(x,y,z) list with more than 10000 coordinates points, everytime i run the program, i can only transform 2530 of those and the loop stops.

Comment: Do you get any Error or `Traceback` message after the 2530th iteration?
 Have you checked what the values of the `2530`th transform values of `x`,`y`,`z` are? I mean, maybe there is something unusual about that 2530th value that causes the code to stop.

Comment: alright good sir, as requested:

Comment: >>> x[2530]
1145303.560007319
>>> y[2530]
-6194655.139512948
>>> z[2530]
994241.3857079013
>>>

Comment: alright, so i did what you said, and you are totally right good sir. is only that point which is causing me troubles. i iterated point N#2531 and it works totally fine.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, yes I ran the code with those values, and it is still running for many minutes, something strange about those values! If we can be of more help, comment here. Otherwise, glad to help you. Cheers friend!

Comment: thank you Mr. Downshift for the help. i am invetigation over a new method to make the transformation. also i run here http://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/coord/llhxyz.htm , with the same values and it worked, so i must improve the code.

Comment: Oh ok, very interesting, I hope you make improvement, if you can't get the solution, update the code with the part that isn't working and we can try to improve together. Until then, good luck and best wishes to you friend.

Comment: for those that want a closure of the subject, here it is. The problem was the method implemented, some points were un-iterative trough this method, yet the library (prypoj) includes an interesting variety of projection transformations, including ECEF-> WSG84(LLA), https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj? ,